How to get parametrized variable from method that returns generic in Java?
For example, I have a parametrized method that accepts class, which variable it should return:
    com. fasterxml. jackson. databind. ObjectMapper
    public <T> T convertValue(Object fromValue, Class<T> toValueType)
    throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    return (T) _convert(fromValue, _typeFactory.constructType(toValueType));
} 

I need to return List<MyObject>, but I can only pass List.class:
objectMapper.convertValue(param1, List.class);

And do Unchecked assignment after that.
Is there a good way to do this operation?

Does this answer your question? Cast Object to Generic Type for returning

If this has to do with Jackson then you might want to take a look at what they've done with type erasure through the TypeReference class: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html

Are you asking how to pass class + generic parameter info to jackson for conversion? Basically objectMapper.convertValue(param1, ListOfMyObject.class);?

There is some relative cleaner to address some of this conversion scenarios but it will depend on what you can you say about the type of objects that need to be casted and the class it has to be casted into at compilation and run-time. For example is it possible that although unknown and compilation time the type input object and return type can be entangled and constrained at some point in runtime?
